# How to update angular component's html file after upload to the server

Tags: angular

Suppose that I have a component in angular project. I want to separate the html page after upload to the site. (after ng-build and upload). The reason is **We want to change the content of the cars.html file time to time.**

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-cars',
  templateUrl: '../../../views/cars.component.html',
  styles: [
  ]
})
export class CarsComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor() { }

  ngOnInit(): void {
  }

}
```

Html file was placed in a view folder.

Now How can I upload the project to the server having cars.component.html seperately and without merging for main.js file?

Thanks  in advance.

Comment: Could a markdown renderer component and writing cars content as markdown work in your use case? Based of [marked.js](https://marked.js.org/), [analogjs](https://github.com/analogjs/analog) have an implementation